# Asus UX21A Zenbook (Win 10): how to boot from a USB flash drive

Tags: boot, usb, bios

Asus UX21A updated from original Win 8 to Win 10 (Asus site shows last BIOS for Win 8, in 2012). I'm trying to do a one-time boot from a USB flash drive formatted for booting, but in BIOS > Boot I'm not seeing the USB stick recognized. Is there a way?

The program I want to create the USB boot disk for is by Samsung and they sent me to unetbootin.github.io, where I chose the Windows version. In BIOS, I deleted the Windows boot and tried to create a new boot reference, adding the USB drive, but it didn't seem to have any effect. The instructions I referred to seeing online didn't resemble what I saw in BIOS. For example, I came across the following user instructions for the UX31:

"In order to see your USB flash drive as a bootable option, you must disable Secure Boot (in the security tab of BIOS) and enable CSM (in the boot tab of BIOS). CSM stands for Compatibility Support Module, and basically allows technology that is not compatible with UEFI to run an emulated legacy BIOS. Anyway, once you've done all that, you should see your flash drive in your boot options."

This seems to post-date the UX21A's BIOS, as I did not find Secure Boot under Security or anywhere else, and didn't see CSM either.

Comment: Information needed, e.g. booting to what OS? Linux? What instructions did you follow in BIOS?

Comment: do not add comments, but edit your question into a cogent whole.